# Why won't this code put the object in an NSMultableArray

Tags: objective-c, object, nsmutablearray

```
[self.lines addObject: [[Line alloc] initWithPosition:CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, _currentHeight)]];

for (Line *line in self.lines) {
    NSLog(@"d");
}

NSLog(@"k");
```

... This will display the K but it wont display and "D"s

Here is the code for the Line class...

```
//Line.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Line : NSObject

@property(assign, nonatomic) int x, y;

- (id)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)pos;
- (void) minusFromX: (int)number;

@end
```

and the other...

```
//Line.m
#import "Line.h"

@implementation Line

- (id)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)pos{

    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _y = pos.y;
        _x = pos.x;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)minusFromX: (int)number{
    _x -= number;
}

@end
```

I apologize because this question is very code based, but I can not seem to find a way to fix it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you create `self.lines` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the array somewhere, like in your view controller's `init` or `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.lines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```